# How to select the maximum value of a column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the maximum value of a column of my table. I'm using PHP and MySQL. This is what I have so far:

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(Id) FROM trialtabel2"; 
$max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max); 
echo= $max1;
```

My debugger is just saying that it is a query returning a `0 boolean value (false)`. I cannot find a specific answer anywhere on the internet.

Comment: post table schema aslo

Comment: You missed fetching part to use simply use `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: I appreciate the effort people have put into answering this simple question and editing my post. If there is any feedback/criticism about my use of SO please do not hesitate to state so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two ways
first is as people described

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(Id) as max_id FROM trialtabel2";     
$max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max);   
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max1); 
$max_id=$row['max_id'];      
echo $max_id;
```

second is ordering and limiting

```
$max_id = 0;
$max = "SELECT id  FROM trialtabel2 order by id desc limit 0,1";    
$max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max);     
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max1)){    
   $max_id=$row['id'];    
}    
echo $max_id;
```

In Your code you missing the fetch statement. you need to fetch from the resultset. see above what you are missing.

Answer (score 5):

You need to `fetch` the data from the `mysqli_result` object that was returned to you when you executed your query using `mysqli_query`.

```
    $max = "SELECT MAX(Id) as id FROM trialtabel2"; 
    $max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max1);    // this was missing
    $id=$row['id'];
    echo $id;
```

Note: I removed the loop because with MAX query without any grouping you will get only 1 row returned. If you had multiple rows in result set you would need to loop through all of them

Comment: This answer is correct but it will be helpful for the OP if you add an explanation of what was wrong and what is added so they can learn

Comment: If you dont mind William i just updated your answer. If you do mind please revert it to previous state. I added an up-vote as well :)

Comment: @Hanky much appreciated...of course i dont. We here to healp each other. Thanks amil man..done

Answer (score 2):

Try using this..,

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(Id) as maxId FROM trialtabel2"; 
$max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max1);
echo $row['maxId'];
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score -2):

```
$max = "SELECT Id FROM trialtabel2 order by id desc limit 1"; 
$max1 =  mysqli_query($dblink, $max); 
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($max1);
pre($result);
```